# I can't get cocoapods to download the correct commit

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

This is the commit I want to download:

https://github.com/MegaBits/MagicalRecord/commit/c72306f862250fe4db4be343fc98a105cac98c6c

In my podfile, I've tried everything. I've even tried commits following that one, changing it's podspec. It simply won't install that commit.

My podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'MagicalRecord', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MegaBits/MagicalRecord/develop/MagicalRecord.podspec'
```

I'm simply out of ideas for this. What do I need to put in that file to download that commit of that project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hm, I can't figure off the top of my head why that's not working.

I'd instead use the following line in your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/MegaBits/MagicalRecord.git', :commit => '679f74eaa3'
```

Although you could leave off the `:commit` bit and have it track whatever changes you make in the fork, including any further changes to the pod spec.

Comment: I try that 
pod 'MetalPetal', :git => 'https://github.com/MetalPetal/MetalPetal.git', branch: 'master'

but it keeps installing version 1.7.0 which is not even the latest pod version.

Answer (score 2):

`pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/MegaBits/MagicalRecord.git', :commit => 'c72306f'`